# Create nested array from existing array

Tags: arrays, ruby, date, multidimensional-array

I'm tying to create an array of dates, based on a user input of the date.  The goal is to take the date input by the user and generate 16 date pairs (in sequential order).

I was able to figure how to generate the start dates and put them in an array, but I can't quite figure out how to take that array and further break them up in to sub-arrays (the date pairs).

Here's the code I used to generate the start dates:

```
@date_pairs = (@input_date-105..@input_date).step(7).to_a.reverse
```

I tried to create a sub-array in the following way:

```
@date_pairs = (@input_date-105..@input_date).step(7).to_a.reverse.each { |x| Array.new(x, x-6)}
```

However I get the following error:  no implicit conversion of Date into Integer

Here's an example of what i'm hoping to get:

```
@input_date = 6/15/2016
@date_pairs = [[6/15/2016, 6/9/2016], [6/8/2016, 6/2/2016], [6/1/2016, 5/24/2016].....]
```

The goal is to be able to iterate over the @date_pairs, accessing each value within the sub-array.

I plan to use this concept to create other types of date pairs (ie, date pairs separated by months, years, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to be sure without knowing what your `@input_date` looks like, but I think you're really close. You're probably getting that error because your `x` is an instance of `DateTime` and you're trying to subtract `6` (an `Integer`) from it. Maybe try subtracting `6.days` instead, like so:

```
@date_pairs = (@input_date-105..@input_date).step(7).to_a.reverse.map { |x| [x, x-6.days] }
```

Also note that `Array.new(5, 6)` produces `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]` -- probably not what you want here.

Hope that helps!